# Command not found in Crontab

Tags: cron

I am new with Crontab and Linux.
I am trying to schedule this following command line instruction in Crontab:

`speedtest-cli --csv  &>> /home/pi/speedtestLog.txt`

I am trying doing it:

`*/1 * * * * speedtest-cli --csv >> /home/pi/speedtestLog.txt 2>&1`

But I am getting the error appended in the file:

`/bin/sh: 1: speedtest-cli: not found`

How do I resolve it please?

Comment: Full path is needed for the command.

Comment: Where is `speedtest-cli`? Use absolute or full path of speedtest-cli in crontab and see if it works.

Comment: @Pilot6 is here `./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but it is not working as well

Comment: `./` is not an absolute path. It should be `/home/<username>...`

Comment: I sorted using the Python script: `python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speedtest.py`

Comment: If you are running Raspbian the default OS of Pi, this question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments above are correct but they don't explain why.

The PATH environment variable is a list of filesystem paths that are searched for executable binaries, which usually looks like:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

The PATH variable is appended by the SHELL you are using.  In ubuntu, /bin/sh links to the default shell, which is *dash* for system boot scripts (i.e. cron).  Dash is similar to *bash* but not identical.  In terminals, *Bash* is used by default.

On Debian-based systems (i.e. Ubuntu), PATH is initialized by pam_env based on the content of /etc/environment:

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

However, the shells like Dash/Bash also source /etc/profile and ~/.profile depending on how they are invoked (interactive vs login shell), where these scripts can append the PATH environment variable.

With all that said, speedtest-cli has to be in a folder on the PATH or you have to specify it using a full path.  If you want option 1, you can try

```
*/1 * * * * . /home/pi/.profile ; speedtest-cli --csv >> /home/pi/speedtestLog.txt 2>&1
```

N.B. Thanks to steeldriver for pointing out that "source .profile" is a bashism and the posix standard is ". .profile".

Comment: @steeldriver I don't have any evidence other than my limited experience with crontab. At some point I had a similar problem and it was solved by adding the path to the executable in the crontab. Since then I always include the full path in a cron job.

Comment: @steeldriver evidence for setting PATH?  From the man crontab(5):

       On  the  Debian  GNU/Linux  system, cron supports the pam_env module, and loads the environment
       specified by /etc/environment and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.  It also reads locale information
       from  /etc/default/locale.   However,  the  PAM settings do NOT override the settings described
       above nor any settings in the crontab file itself. Note in particular that if you want  a  PATH
       other than "/usr/bin:/bin", you will need to set it in the crontab file